# Windows Azure queue GetMessage returns null

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-queues

I have a Windows Azure queue of CloudQueue. I use `queue.GetMessage` to retrieve message from queue, but it returns null.

I initialize my queue as below:

```
var setting = CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("DataConnectionString");
var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(setting);
var queueClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudQueueClient();
var queue = queueClient.GetQueueReference(RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue("QueueName"));
queue.CreateIfNotExists();
```

After that I add CloudQueueMessage in that queue like this:

```
CloudQueueMessage msg = new CloudQueueMessage(content);      
queue.AddMessage(msg);
```

When I check Message count:

```
queue.FetchAttributes();
int? count = queue.ApproximateMessageCount;  //returns 1
```

I get that count equals to 1, but when I try to get message:

```
var retrievedMsg = queue.GetMessage();    // returns null
```

I have `retrievedMsg` is `null`.

I'm confused. I have no code in but this in this method. But everytime I have retrieved message is null.

Any ideas?

Comment: This is weird! You would get null when there're no messages to be dequeued. Which version of storage client library are you using? Is this against a cloud storage account or local storage account (emulator version)?

Comment: I have used Windows Azure ver 2.2, so Microsoft.VindowsAzure.Storage ver 3.0.3.0, Windows Azure Emulator is 2.2. But it is to be mentioned that i have this bug after upgrading Windows azure from v1.7. While upgrading i adopt some code. But i have no other issues but this.

Comment: Is the role that hosts your code single instanced? Coz if it's configured to have 2 or more instances, it could be that queue.GetMessage is reached by one of the instances before you reach it in the instance that you are dubugging.

Comment: Yes. you are right. I have a staging that extract all my queue's messages before my local version do that. So I change my configuration to use Storage Emulator. But need to use Emulator ver 2.2.1 preview.

Answer (score 0):

Another option for getting started is to start with code that definitely works and then we can work backwards. Install the latest Azure SDK (2.5) and it will install some quickstarts directly in VS. From VS select File / New / Project / Cloud / Azure Storage Queues. Then update the app.config file to point to your service account. Confirm that works. Then it is either your code or some other environmental issue (multiple readers, etc).